# Markdown rendering missing in comment flags under moderator

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

Code formatting isn't properly rendered within comment flags:

[image]

... and links (possibly other content) as well:

[image]

I doubt there would be any nefarious content that is hidden through markdown that one would want to expose. And even if that's the case, I anticipate that moderators would use consideration with any posted content they are moderating.

Is this non-formatting intended? If not, can it be fixed to render in the same way?

Comment: If there isn't a display of the Markdown source, then there's no stock way to know if the user has included invisible links, or, potentially, other nefarious content. With the Markdown displayed in the flag handling dialog/dashboard, moderators can see exactly what was actually included in the comment: [example of what it looks like with the stock UI in the dialog/dashboard with invisible links in the comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7N0z.png).

Comment: @Makyen: I tried to replicate your comment in the [Meta Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment1248136_3122). but was unable to. Can you provide a means to do this? Are those invisible links clickable?

Comment: I'm sorry for not responding at the time to your above comment. I haven't looked for the original comment I used to create the above screenshot, but created a comment in the [Meta Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment1307416_3122) which has the same issue.

Comment: While there are probably other ways to accomplish it, that comment uses the text `This[​](https://example.com/) comment[​](https://example.com/) has[​](https://example.com/) a[​](https://example.com/) number[​](https://example.com/) of[​](https://example.com/) invisible[​](https://example.com/) links[​](https://example.com/) hidden[​](https://example.com/) between[​](https://example.com/) the[​](https://example.com/) words`.

Comment: The key is to use an appropriate Unicode character within the `[]`, so it's parsed as a link. In this case I used a Zero Width Space, ->​<-, which is an easy go-to character to use in such circumstances.

Comment: The comment there was: This[​](https://example.com/) comment[​](https://example.com/) has[​](https://example.com/) a[​](https://example.com/) number[​](https://example.com/) of[​](https://example.com/) invisible[​](https://example.com/) links[​](https://example.com/) hidden[​](https://example.com/) between[​](https://example.com/) the[​](https://example.com/) words.